# What are the different microsoft created Workflow templates for?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I'm trying to create my first workflow. I can't find a reference for what the use cases or primary uses are for the different project types I'm finding in VS2010 ultimate. I'm interested almost exclusively in Microsoft developed workflow templates.

I currently have showing:

- Activity Designer Library
- Activity Library
- WCF Workflow Service Application
- Workflow Console Application

what are the major differences? do any of them implement a nice view while running of what's going on? (like SSIS or DTS)

Am I missing microsoft templates from an SDK or Extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I understand them:

1. Activity Designer Library - This
   project type lets you control the
   look of an Activity Designer used
   for creating workflows. It
   provides full XAML control for
   re-skinning the WF Designer, in
   essense.
2. Activity Library - Similar to the Class Library project type, this is for defining activities that will be leveraged in other Workflows.
3. WCF Workflow Service Application - Specifically for Workflows fronted by WCF Services. In these Workflows, one or more entry or exit points of the workflow is managed by WCF endpoints.
4. Workflow Console Application - Creates a simple workflow definition and a default Program.cs implementation that allows you to run and test the Workflow. Great for demos or getting started with a Workflow.

Beyond these four, the WF Page on Codeplex has some other great resources and the team adds extensions and guidance pretty often, from what I've seen. Check out: http://wf.codeplex.com/. At this moment, they have a few activity packs up (State Machine, ADO.NET) as well as a 3.0 migration pack and a security library. It's a good resource to keep an eye on.